# cqlsh getting started gives invalid syntax

Tags: cassandra, cqlsh

I'm following http://wiki.apache.org/cassandra/GettingStarted

The first thing I do in `cqlsh` is

```
cqlsh> CREATE KEYSPACE mykeyspace WITH REPLICATION = {'class' : 'SimpleStrategy', 'replication_factor' : 1 };
Invalid syntax at line 1, char 47
  CREATE KEYSPACE mykeyspace WITH REPLICATION = {'class' : 'SimpleStrategy', 'replication_factor' : 1 };
                                                ^
cqlsh>
```

What am I doing wrong?

```
cqlsh> SHOW VERSION;
[cqlsh 2.2.0 | Cassandra 1.1.12 | CQL spec 2.0.0 | Thrift protocol 19.33.0]
cqlsh>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution was that the Cassandra page for installing from deb wasn't very clear to me:

> Alternatively, you can install directly from the ASF repositories:
>
> deb http://www.apache.org/dist/cassandra/debian 11x main
>
> deb-src http://www.apache.org/dist/cassandra/debian 11x main
>
> You will want to replace 11x by the series you want to use: `10x for
>   the 1.0.x series, 08x for the 0.8.x series, etc... You will not
>   automatically get major version updates unless you change the series,
>   but that is a feature.

As it had 11x in the documentation I assumed that was the latest version rather than 20x as it should have been, then everything worked.

Answer (score 2):

use below thing it will work.

CREATE SCHEMA mykeyspace WITH replication = { 'class' : 'SimpleStrategy', 'replication_factor' : 1 };

Comment: Same problem for me  cqlsh> CREATE SCHEMA mykeyspace WITH replication = { 'class' : 'SimpleStrategy', 'replication_factor' : 1 };
Invalid syntax at line 1, char 45
  CREATE SCHEMA mykeyspace WITH replication = { 'class' : 'SimpleStrategy', 'replication_factor' : 1 };
                                              ^
cqlsh>

Comment: Seems to be a problem with curly braces, could this be something to do with my python install?

Comment: which version of python you are using ? you must have to use 2.7 version of Python..

Comment: 2.7.6 but it seems apt installed version 2.2.0 of cqlsh which seems to be quite old.  I have no idea how I update this.

Comment: I installed the latest cqlsh with pip, now I get  cql.cassandra.ttypes.InvalidRequestException: InvalidRequestException(why='Provided version 3.1.1 is not supported by this server (supported: 2.0.0, 3.0.0-beta1)')
➜  user git:(feature/esperJms) ✗ /usr/local/bin/cqlsh --version
cqlsh 4.1.1

Comment: remove cassandra completely and set-it up from the begining. refer below links..
http://cassandra.apache.org/
http://cassandra.apache.org/download/

Answer (score 1):

I'm only going to mention this here because I had the same problem.

There's always a chance that if you're copy/pasting from a text editor that's using some different encoding or has some hidden whitespace characters, the cqlsh client is breaking on those invalid characters.  In those cases, it's always worth typing it out just be sure.

Comment: This is exactly what happened when I pasted to `cqlsh` a python-generated `create table` query with a long list of columns copied from Jupyter Notebook... I initially thought I came across some string size limit in `cqlsh`.

Comment: ...but Instead of re-typing the query (it may be long!) it's sufficient to paste is to a plain text editor (like Text Editor or Notepad) and copy it again from there.